# Swap two lists in c#

Tags: c#

I have a List of a List (a matrix, which is sent via web.api HTTP POST from matlab).

```
List<List<decimal>> mylist;
```

The size of the matrix is `nxm`, how can I swap those lists? i.e.

```
mylist[i][j] --> mylist[j][i]
```

In Matlab the operation would be `mylist'` or in mathematical context (*transposing*)

```
mylist^T
```

Comment: Anything tried? Sample lists and an expected result available?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the expected result is in the question, @derloopkat not required, may be `mxn` (as in the question mentioned)

Comment: @robert: well, then this is my answer: `mylist[i][j] = mylist[j][i]`

Comment: @TimSchmelter that won't work and you know that. I think the question is clear enough, at least someone (AliAdlavaran) understood it right away

Comment: I think this operation is called "transposing" - @RobertStettler so did I, I think Tim is trying to make questions understandable for _anyone_ (but I'm not going to judge if an example is really needed in this case)

Comment: I added the terms and some more information. Thanks @C.Evenhuis

Comment: I think array is more meaningful than list in your operation. You should keep your inner list in same in count. right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter as far as the accepted solution is concerned, yes. However: there is it reduced to linq, I don't think that should be a requirement. If you feel the urge to flag this question, go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Linq` to achieve that without `for` loop like this:

```
var swapedList = 
   mylist
   .SelectMany((l, i) => l.Select((d, j) => new { i, j, d }))
   .GroupBy(l=>l.j)
   .Select(l=>l.Select(ll=>ll.d).ToList());
   .ToList();
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: Works perfectly